# Exception while starting Weblogic Managed Server

Tags: java, oracle, weblogic, business-process-management

I tried to start Weblogic managed server and I'm getting the exception below:

```
Apr 11, 2011 10:08:16 PM PDT> <Error> <oracle.bam.adc.dse.common.DataSourceFactory> <BEA-000000> <[12] Exception occurred in method DataSourceFactory.getDataSource(jdbc/oracle/bam/adc)
Exception: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: While trying to lookup 'jdbc.oracle.bam/adc' didn't find subcontext 'oracle'. Resolved 'jdbc'; remaining name 'oracle/bam/adc'
  at weblogic.jndi.internal.BasicNamingNode.newNameNotFoundException(BasicNamingNode.java:1139)
  at weblogic.jndi.internal.BasicNamingNode.lookupHere(BasicNamingNode.java:247)
  at weblogic.jndi.internal.ServerNamingNode.lookupHere(ServerNamingNode.java:182)
  at weblogic.jndi.internal.BasicNamingNode.lookup(BasicNamingNode.java:206)
  at weblogic.jndi.internal.BasicNamingNode.lookup(BasicNamingNode.java:214)
  at weblogic.jndi.internal.WLEventContextImpl.lookup(WLEventContextImpl.java:254)
  at weblogic.jndi.internal.WLContextImpl.lookup(WLContextImpl.java:411)
  at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:392)
  at oracle.bam.adc.dse.common.DataSourceFactory.getDataSource(DataSourceFactory.java:132)
  at oracle.bam.adc.dse.common.DataSourceFactory.getDataSource(DataSourceFactory.java:105)
  at oracle.bam.adc.dse.common.StorageEngineFactory.startup(StorageEngineFactory.java:109)
  at oracle.bam.adc.kernel.server.DataStoreServer.startup(DataStoreServer.java:234)
  at oracle.bam.adc.kernel.server.ADCService.startService(ADCService.java:83)
  at oracle.bam.server.BamServer$ServiceEntry$1.run(BamServer.java:1716)
  at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
  at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAsPrivileged(Subject.java:517)
  at oracle.security.jps.internal.jaas.AccActionExecutor.execute(AccActionExecutor.java:47)
  at oracle.security.jps.internal.jaas.CascadeActionExecutor$SubjectPrivilegedExceptionAction.run(CascadeActionExecutor.java:79)
  at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:363)
  at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:146)
  at weblogic.security.Security.runAs(Security.java:61)
  at oracle.security.jps.wls.jaas.WlsActionExecutor.execute(WlsActionExecutor.java:48)
  at oracle.security.jps.internal.jaas.CascadeActionExecutor.execute(CascadeActionExecutor.java:52)
  at oracle.bam.common.security.authentication.BamPrivilegedExceptionAction.execute(BamPrivilegedExceptionAction.java:153)
  at oracle.bam.common.security.authentication.BamPrivilegedExceptionAction.execute(BamPrivilegedExceptionAction.java:121)
  at oracle.bam.server.BamServer$ServiceEntry.start(BamServer.java:1722)
  at oracle.bam.server.BamServer.init(BamServer.java:272)
  at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletInitAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:283)
  at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
  at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
  at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.createServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:64)
  at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubLifecycleHelper.createOneInstance(StubLifecycleHelper.java:58)
  at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubLifecycleHelper.<init>(StubLifecycleHelper.java:48)
  at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.prepareServlet(ServletStubImpl.java:539)
  at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.preloadServlet(WebAppServletContext.java:1985)
  at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.loadServletsOnStartup(WebAppServletContext.java:1959)
  at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.preloadResources(WebAppServletContext.java:1878)
  at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.start(WebAppServletContext.java:3153)
  at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.startContexts(WebAppModule.java:1508)
  at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.start(WebAppModule.java:482)
  at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:425)
  at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:52)
  at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:119)
  at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ScopedModuleDriver.start(ScopedModuleDriver.java:200)
  at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.start(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:247)
  at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:425)
  at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:52)
  at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:119)
  at weblogic.application.internal.flow.StartModulesFlow.activate(StartModulesFlow.java:27)
  at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$2.next(BaseDeployment.java:636)
  at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:52)
  at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.activate(BaseDeployment.java:205)
  at weblogic.application.internal.EarDeployment.activate(EarDeployment.java:58)
  at weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.activate(DeploymentStateChecker.java:161)
  at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.activate(AppContainerInvoker.java:79)
  at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.BasicDeployment.activate(BasicDeployment.java:184)
  at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.BasicDeployment.activateFromServerLifecycle(BasicDeployment.java:361)
  at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentAdapter$1.doActivate(DeploymentAdapter.java:51)
  at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentAdapter.activate(DeploymentAdapter.java:200)
  at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.AppTransition$2.transitionApp(AppTransition.java:30)
  at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.ConfiguredDeployments.transitionApps(ConfiguredDeployments.java:261)
  at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.ConfiguredDeployments.transitionApps(ConfiguredDeployments.java:246)
  at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.ConfiguredDeployments.activate(ConfiguredDeployments.java:169)
  at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.ConfiguredDeployments.deploy(ConfiguredDeployments.java:123)
  at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentServerService.resume(DeploymentServerService.java:180)
  at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentServerService.start(DeploymentServerService.java:96)
  at weblogic.t3.srvr.SubsystemRequest.run(SubsystemRequest.java:64)
  at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:207)
  at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:176)
>
<Apr 11, 2011 10:08:16 PM PDT> <Error> <HTTP> <BEA-101216> <Servlet: "BamServer" failed to preload on startup in Web application: "/oracle/bam".
java.lang.Exception: BAM data store server failed to start.
        at oracle.bam.adc.kernel.server.DataStoreServer.startup(DataStoreServer.java:323)
        at oracle.bam.adc.kernel.server.ADCService.startService(ADCService.java:83)
        at oracle.bam.server.BamServer$ServiceEntry$1.run(BamServer.java:1716)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAsPrivileged(Subject.java:517)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: While trying to lookup 'jdbc.oracle.bam/adc' didn't find subcontext 'oracle'. Resolved 'jdbc'; remaining name 'oracle/bam/adc'
        at weblogic.jndi.internal.BasicNamingNode.newNameNotFoundException(BasicNamingNode.java:1139)
        at weblogic.jndi.internal.BasicNamingNode.lookupHere(BasicNamingNode.java:247)
        at weblogic.jndi.internal.ServerNamingNode.lookupHere(ServerNamingNode.java:182)
        at weblogic.jndi.internal.BasicNamingNode.lookup(BasicNamingNode.java:206)
        at weblogic.jndi.internal.BasicNamingNode.lookup(BasicNamingNode.java:214)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
>
<Apr 11, 2011 10:08:16 PM PDT> <Error> <Deployer> <BEA-149231> <Unable to set the activation state to true for the application 'oracle-bam [Version=11.1.1]'.
weblogic.application.ModuleException: [HTTP:101216]Servlet: "BamServer" failed to preload on startup in Web application: "/oracle/bam".
java.lang.Exception: BAM data store server failed to start.
        at oracle.bam.adc.kernel.server.DataStoreServer.startup(DataStoreServer.java:323)
        at oracle.bam.adc.kernel.server.ADCService.startService(ADCService.java:83)
        at oracle.bam.server.BamServer$ServiceEntry$1.run(BamServer.java:1716)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAsPrivileged(Subject.java:517)
        at oracle.security.jps.internal.jaas.AccActionExecutor.execute(AccActionExecutor.java:47)
        at oracle.security.jps.internal.jaas.CascadeActionExecutor$SubjectPrivilegedExceptionAction.run(CascadeActionExecutor.java:79)
        at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:363)
        at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:146)
        at weblogic.security.Security.runAs(Security.java:61)
        at oracle.security.jps.wls.jaas.WlsActionExecutor.execute(WlsActionExecutor.java:48)
        at oracle.security.jps.internal.jaas.CascadeActionExecutor.execute(CascadeActionExecutor.java:52)
        at oracle.bam.common.security.authentication.BamPrivilegedExceptionAction.execute(BamPrivilegedExceptionAction.java:153)
        at oracle.bam.common.security.authentication.BamPrivilegedExceptionAction.execute(BamPrivilegedExceptionAction.java:121)
        at oracle.bam.server.BamServer$ServiceEntry.start(BamServer.java:1722)
        at oracle.bam.server.BamServer.init(BamServer.java:272)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletInitAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:283)
        at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
        at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.createServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:64)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubLifecycleHelper.createOneInstance(StubLifecycleHelper.java:58)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubLifecycleHelper.<init>(StubLifecycleHelper.java:48)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.prepareServlet(ServletStubImpl.java:539)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.preloadServlet(WebAppServletContext.java:1985)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.loadServletsOnStartup(WebAppServletContext.java:1959)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.preloadResources(WebAppServletContext.java:1878)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.start(WebAppServletContext.java:3153)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.startContexts(WebAppModule.java:1508)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.start(WebAppModule.java:482)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:425)
        at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:52)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:119)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ScopedModuleDriver.start(ScopedModuleDriver.java:200)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.start(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:247)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:425)
        at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:52)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:119)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.StartModulesFlow.activate(StartModulesFlow.java:27)
        at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$2.next(BaseDeployment.java:636)
        at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:52)
        at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.activate(BaseDeployment.java:205)
        at weblogic.application.internal.EarDeployment.activate(EarDeployment.java:58)
        at weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.activate(DeploymentStateChecker.java:161)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.activate(AppContainerInvoker.java:79)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.BasicDeployment.activate(BasicDeployment.java:184)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.BasicDeployment.activateFromServerLifecycle(BasicDeployment.java:361)
        at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentAdapter$1.doActivate(DeploymentAdapter.java:51)
        at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentAdapter.activate(DeploymentAdapter.java:200)
        at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.AppTransition$2.transitionApp(AppTransition.java:30)
        at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.ConfiguredDeployments.transitionApps(ConfiguredDeployments.java:261)
        at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.ConfiguredDeployments.transitionApps(ConfiguredDeployments.java:246)
        at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.ConfiguredDeployments.activate(ConfiguredDeployments.java:169)
        at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.ConfiguredDeployments.deploy(ConfiguredDeployments.java:123)
        at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentServerService.resume(DeploymentServerService.java:180)
        at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentServerService.start(DeploymentServerService.java:96)
        at weblogic.t3.srvr.SubsystemRequest.run(SubsystemRequest.java:64)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:207)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:176)
Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: While trying to lookup 'jdbc.oracle.bam/adc' didn't find subcontext 'oracle'. Resolved 'jdbc'; remaining name 'oracle/bam/adc'
        at weblogic.jndi.internal.BasicNamingNode.newNameNotFoundException(BasicNamingNode.java:1139)
        at weblogic.jndi.internal.BasicNamingNode.lookupHere(BasicNamingNode.java:247)
        at weblogic.jndi.internal.ServerNamingNode.lookupHere(ServerNamingNode.java:182)
        at weblogic.jndi.internal.BasicNamingNode.lookup(BasicNamingNode.java:206)
        at weblogic.jndi.internal.BasicNamingNode.lookup(BasicNamingNode.java:214)
        at weblogic.jndi.internal.WLEventContextImpl.lookup(WLEventContextImpl.java:254)
        at weblogic.jndi.internal.WLContextImpl.lookup(WLContextImpl.java:411)
        at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:392)
        at oracle.bam.adc.dse.common.DataSourceFactory.getDataSource(DataSourceFactory.java:132)
        at oracle.bam.adc.dse.common.DataSourceFactory.getDataSource(DataSourceFactory.java:105)
        at oracle.bam.adc.dse.common.StorageEngineFactory.startup(StorageEngineFactory.java:109)
        at oracle.bam.adc.kernel.server.DataStoreServer.startup(DataStoreServer.java:234)
        ... 57 more

        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.startContexts(WebAppModule.java:1510)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.start(WebAppModule.java:482)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:425)
        at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:52)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:119)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: While trying to lookup 'jdbc.oracle.bam/adc' didn't find subcontext 'oracle'. Resolved 'jdbc'; remaining name 'oracle/bam/adc'
        at weblogic.jndi.internal.BasicNamingNode.newNameNotFoundException(BasicNamingNode.java:1139)
        at weblogic.jndi.internal.BasicNamingNode.lookupHere(BasicNamingNode.java:247)
        at weblogic.jndi.internal.ServerNamingNode.lookupHere(ServerNamingNode.java:182)
        at weblogic.jndi.internal.BasicNamingNode.lookup(BasicNamingNode.java:206)
        at weblogic.jndi.internal.BasicNamingNode.lookup(BasicNamingNode.java:214)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
>
<Apr 11, 2011 10:08:16 PM PDT> <Notice> <Log Management> <BEA-170027> <The Server has established connection with the Domain level Diagnostic Service successfully.>
<Apr 11, 2011 10:08:17 PM PDT> <Notice> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000365> <Server state changed to ADMIN>
<Apr 11, 2011 10:08:17 PM PDT> <Notice> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000365> <Server state changed to RESUMING>
<Apr 11, 2011 10:08:17 PM PDT> <Notice> <Server> <BEA-002613> <Channel "Default[1]" is now listening on 127.0.0.1:9001 for protocols iiop, iiop, t3, t3, ldap, ldap, snmp, snmp, http, http.>
<Apr 11, 2011 10:08:17 PM PDT> <Notice> <Server> <BEA-002613> <Channel "Default[2]" is now listening on 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:9001 for protocols iiop, t3, ldap, snmp, http.>
<Apr 11, 2011 10:08:17 PM PDT> <Notice> <Server> <BEA-002613> <Channel "Default" is now listening on 10.152.105.211:9001 for protocols iiop, t3, ldap, snmp, http.>
<Apr 11, 2011 10:08:17 PM PDT> <Notice> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000332> <Started WebLogic Managed Server "ManagedServer" for domain "bpms_poc_domain" running in Development Mode>
<Apr 11, 2011 10:08:30 PM PDT> <Notice> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000365> <Server state changed to RUNNING>
<Apr 11, 2011 10:08:30 PM PDT> <Notice> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000360> <Server started in RUNNING mode>
```

Due to this exception, my Oracle-BAM service doesn't start. I need to start the same.

Can someone give me pointers?

Regards,
Arvind K

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure you've configured DataSource under JNDI name `jdbc.oracle.bam/adc`. This should be described in the administration guide.

I know that answer is too broad but that's exactly what exception you got means.

Answer (score 2):

Also, make sure the JDBC datasource is targeted to the managed server or cluster where BAM is targeted.  The Admin Console will let you get away with configuring a datasource but not targeting it to any servers or clusters.

Answer (score 1):

I created a new data source with JNDI name: jdbc/oracle/bam/adc and restarted the servers and the error vanished. Looks like the JNDI with the above name was not present by default (which shouldn't have been the case ?).

Thanks for the inputs guys.

Arvind K

Answer (score 0):

JDBC/JNDI ISSUE, undeply app and reconfigure it from console, also check required jars are in platform/domain lib folder

hopefully this will helps